# Java keyListener with multiple JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener, key-bindings

I'm having a problem with Java `KeyListener` when adding adding another `JPanel` with 5 `JLabels`, I've searched around this website, and most solutions to this problem involve switching from `KeyListener` to `KeyBindings`. This wont work for me because I need to know exactly when a key is pressed, released and held down. To my knowledge, `KeyBindings` does not provide all those.

I've tried to use

```
this.requestFocus();
```

after creating the new `JPanel`, but it didn't work, however when I use the same line inside the `paintComponent()`, it works. Which brings me to my questions: How does this reflect on performance? My `paintComponent()` is called about 60 times/sec. Is  there a way to call it once and still have this working? I see that `requestDefaultFocus()` from the type `JComponent` is deprecated...

I've also tried adding same KeyListener to the second JPanel, but that didn't help. Im guessing one of the JLabels is the one that gets focus?

Answer (score 2):

> This wont work for me because I need to know exactly when a key is pressed, released and held down. To my knowledge, KeyBindings does not provide all those.

Yes it does. You have an Action for "pressed" and "released". There is no such Action as "held down" (even for a KeyListener), you just get multiple events generated.

```
this.requestFocus();
```

That is not the proper method to use for requestion focus on a component. Read the API for that method and it will tell you the proper method to use.

> however when I use the same line inside the paintComponent(), it works.

This is because you can't request focus on a component until the frame has been realized, which means you've invoked pack() or setVisible() on the frame.

> Is there a way to call it once and still have this working?

See the `RequestFocusListener` class in [Dialog Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/).

The proper solution is to use Key Bindings so you don't need to use these work arounds.